# Compile WASM file from docker-compose

Tags: go, docker-compose, webassembly

I need to incorporate the wasm build process into docker-compose.

While running docker-compose I get the following error:

```
can't load package: cannot find module providing package wasm.go: unrecognized import path "wasm.go": https fetch: Get "https://wasm.go/?go-get=1":
```

I attempted to use a go.mod next to the docker-compose.yml but that gives me the exact same error.

Below are the files are in use.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version : '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: library/mysql:8.0
    container_name: container_mysql
    env_file:
      - ./MySQL/.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ./MySQL/sql-scripts/test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: container_phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80

  app:
    container_name: container_api
    command: /bin/sh -c "./script.compile.wasm.sh"
    env_file:
      - ./Go/.env
    build:
      context: ./Go
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

**wasm.go**

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall/js"
)

func key(this js.Value, arg []js.Value) interface{} {
    arg[0].Call("stopPropagation")
    arg[0].Call("preventDefault")
    return nil
}

func sum(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    var rv interface{}

    value1 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "num1").Get("value").String()
    value2 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "num2").Get("value").String()

    int1, _ := strconv.Atoi(value1)
    int2, _ := strconv.Atoi(value2)

    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "result").Set("value", int1+int2)
    return rv
}

func register_callbacks() {
    js.Global().Set("key", js.FuncOf(key))
    js.Global().Set("sum", js.FuncOf(sum))
}

func main() {
    register_callbacks()
    appKey := os.Getenv("APP_KEY")
    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "env").Set("value", appKey)
    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", "env2").Set("value", "hardcoded")
    select {}
}
```

**script.compile.wasm.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o ./Go/assets/main.wasm main.wasm.go
```

File structure looks like:

```
|app/docker-compose.yml
|app/wasm.go
|app/script.compile.wasm.sh
|app/Go
|app/Go/assets
```

Running the script alone works fine

```
app$ ./script.compile.wasm.sh
```